# problem of date picker validation on update user data

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, datepicker, formbuilder

I'm trying to add/update user accounts using a dialog form (add and update on some dialog and the system decide type of operation by a value of a variable injected by the main component to the dialog) the problem is when I tried to launch the update I found that my date picker launch validation error (but I didn't put any validation condition on it) and the submit button gets disabled here is a pic of my update form.
[image]

and here the code my html:

```
        <form [formGroup]="profileForm" class="event-form w-100-p" fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
...
 <div fxFlex="1 0 auto" fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row">

                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="pr-sm-8" fxFlex="100">
                    <mat-label>Date de naissance</mat-label>
                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="startDatePicker"  formControlName="birthday">
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #startDatePicker ></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>

            </div>
...
<div mat-dialog-actions class="m-0 p-16" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center">

        <button  mat-button color="primary"
                class="save-button"
                (click)="onaccept()"
                [disabled]="profileForm.invalid"
                aria-label="ADD">
                {{ActionType}}
        </button>

    </div>
```

component.ts:

```
profileForm = this.fb.group({
    Nom_de_famille: ['' ,Validators.required],//
    Prénom: ['' ,Validators.required],//
    email: ['', [Validators.email,Validators.required]],//
    Code_personnel: [,Validators.compose( [Validators.min(1000), Validators.max(9999)])],//Validators.required
    N_tel: [''],
    birthday: [''],
    adresse: [''],
    lieu:[''],
    CIN:['',Validators.compose([Validators.min(10000000), Validators.max(99999999)])],
    Genre:[''],
    N_permis:[''],
    Département: ['',Validators.required]
  });
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditNewChauffeursComponent>, private fb: FormBuilder)
  ngOnInit() {
       this.setdefaultformvalues(this.indata.SendData);
}
 setdefaultformvalues(row) {
    this.profileForm.patchValue({
      Nom_de_famille: [row.FirstName],
      Prénom: [row.LastName],
      email: [row.Email],
      Code_personnel: [row.DriverCode],
      N_tel: [row.Tel],
      birthday: [''],
      adresse: [row.Address],
      lieu:[row.BirthPlace],
      CIN:[row.CIN],
      Genre:[row.DriverLicenseType],
      N_permis:[row.DriverLicenseNumber],
      Département: [row.DepartmentId]
    });

  }
```

Comment: To be honest, your code looks fine. Whats the exact error on the birthday `FormControl`? Do you set the state of your input explicitly as touched somewhere in your code?

Comment: Honestly, there is no error message on my date picker, And yeah just I let the date input empty and there is no required condition as U see, So I don't understand anything;

Comment: Well there should be a `matDatepickerParse ` error and there seems to be an issue at github https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10861.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `setdefaultformvalues` do this:

```
birthday: null,
```

instead of

```
birthday: [''],
```

Answer (score 0):

can you add a console log of profileForm after you fill it and check controls object in it you will see all your controls in there then check birthday control and you will see error key in there check what the error

[this an example of it]